# SegmentedControl doesn't detect change

Tags: ios, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol, xcode5

I use a SegmentedControl to hide and show labels etc.
But it doesn't detect the change.

Here's the .h:

```
IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *chby;    
-(IBAction)changeby:(id)sender;
```

Here's the .m:

```
-(IBAction)changeby:(id)sender{
    int selct = chby.selectedSegmentIndex;
    NSLog(@"Selected: %d",selct);
}
```

The log says every time selected: 0

Can anyone help me?

Comment: replace `int selct = chby.selectedSegmentIndex;` with `int selct = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;` and see what happens. My guess is that you haven't connected the control to the outlet.

Comment: I tried it and saw that i made a stupid mistake, because I forgot to connect the UISegmented control with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) on usage. Please make sure you are not using touch-up inside as you default action event. The correct one to use for this control is mention in the docs as the :UIControlEventValueChanged (value changed event). If this helps feel free to accept the answer otherwise leave a comment with further detail.

Hope this helps.